# How to read the user Ids from given Query?

Tags: apex, soql, developer-console

I'm trying to fetch user id's from the below SOQL query please help

```
   List<Id> userIds = new List<Id>();
   List<CaseShare> csList = [select id,CaseId,UserOrGroupId from CaseShare where CaseId = 'xxxxxxx' ];
   for(CaseShare cshare :csList  ){
      List<Id> ids = cshare.get(UserOrGroupId) ;
       userIds.add(ids);

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify based on the prefix of the id.

For the user salesforce allocated the **005** prefix in id.

Try this:

```
List<Id> userIds = new List<Id>();
List<CaseShare> csList = [SELECT Id, CaseId, UserOrGroupId FROM CaseShare WHERE CaseId = 'xxxxxxx' ];
for(CaseShare cshare :csList  ){
    String uId = String.valueOf(cshare.UserOrGroupId);
    if(uId.startsWith('005') ){        
        userIds.add(cshare.UserOrGroupId);
    }    
}
system.debug('userIds-->'+userIds);
```

You can also try like the below:

```
Map<Id, User> userIds = new Map<Id, User>([
    SELECT Id
    FROM USER
    WHERE Id IN (
      SELECT UserOrGroupId 
      FROM CaseShare 
      WHERE (CaseId = '5000o00003duNYaAAM' AND UserOrGroup.Type = 'user'))
  ]);
system.debug('userIds-->'+userIds.keySet());
```

Comment: Hi Tushar, Thanks for your quick help. In your code used this line userIds.add(ids); but have not declared  (Ids) anywhere

Comment: Check now. I have updated the code.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error Tushar - Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void startsWith(String) from the type Id please help

Comment: Check now. I have updated the code.

Comment: You can also use this query to get only user ids. `SELECT UserOrGroup.Type , UserOrGroupId FROM CaseShare WHERE (CaseId = '500xxxxxxxxxxxxx' AND UserOrGroup.Type = 'user')`